# In selenium, is there a way to verify if there are images in the body of the webpage?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

Is there a way to list images ONLY from the body of the webpage excluding header and Footer? I need to write the script to verify if my webpage contains no image/multimedia content- This excludes Header and Footer which contains images. 
How do I filter just from the body of the webpage?

This is the structure of my webpage.

```
<header>
<main>
<div class="sublayout sl001-row common">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="sublayout sl022-1-col ">
<div class="c001-heading-text ">
<div class="c002-subheading-text">
<div class="rte-limited">


<div class="sublayout sl022-1-col "> - contains the objects in the body of the webpage.
```

**html code**

```
</header>

<main>
    <div class="sublayout sl001-row common">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sublayout sl022-1-col ">
<div class="c001-heading-text ">
 <h1>ABC</h1>
</div>


<div class="c002-subheading-text">
    <div class="c021-rte-limited">
        <h2>Titularidad</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the html code? how your images look in html code? what have you tried so far? without these information this question doesn't make any sense. but the answer of your question is, YES

Comment: Define "Images": Would just <img> tags count or background images as well? What about inline <SVG> graphics?

Comment: Just filtering out img tags would suffice.

Comment: I have images in header and footer. That is why i am unable to just filter using img tag on the webpage. I want to validate if there are any in the body of the page.

Answer (score 0):

From what you write, I do not understand very well what you want to do. From what I can understand is just a simple xpath query that will give you all the img tags and check that the list is full.
You can check:

```
.....

List<WebElement> imgChildElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body//img"));
if (!imgChildElements.isEmpty()) {
    //images in the page
}
```

Comment: try putting things like this in comments. not in answer section.

Comment: sorry, but i can't put comment yet.

Comment: I have edited the request. Please let me know if it is still not clear.

Comment: If you want to know how to find images in the body, the code I posted should work.

Comment: i used - List<WebElement> imagesList = driver.findElements(By.xpath("html//body//main//div//div//div//div//img"));

Comment: Great, for the semantic of xpath you can also directly use html//body//img